# How can one create clickable output logs for Xcode debugging?

Tags: xcode, debugging

In Visual Studio I can set a log format in the logger that will output lines to OutputDebugString(). such that it is clickable. That is clicking on on the line in the debug output window and will send me to the file and line specified in the log line.

For Visual Studio I have the logger output a line formatted like this:

```
INFO OsCanvasWindow.cpp(121) OsCanvasWindow : Require extension: VK_EXT_metal_surface
```

This format does not work that way in the Xcode output window.
Is there a format one can use for Xcode that enables the same functionality?

So far I haven't found such a thing.

It is extremely useful.